# A conflicting title edit should not stop other edits from being saved

Tags: feature-request, edits

While I was working on a edit ([revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7756439/revisions)) somebody else committed revision 2, fixing the typo in the question title. This prevented me from saving my edit, clicking on "Save Changes" repeatedly just informed me that somebody else edited the post title and that I should start my edit again from scratch.

To get my changes committed I had to open a new edit window and copy-paste the post contents there.

I should be able to just save my changes anyway, if I think its an improvement over the previous edit.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't attempt to save your edit without considering the previous edit.  It might contain edits that overlap (such as fixing a grammar edit of the same phrase in two different ways) or it might change the meaning of the question and invalidate your edit.

A three-way merge tool is one solution to this problem, but it's not such a pressing issue that the team needs to implement some fancy interface with source and previews for several revisions.

I could support updating the information dialog with a link to the revisions page showing the previous and current state of the post, with instructions to merge your edit if the post still needs editing. However, in no case should an edit be posted without considering the previous edit.

Comment: But I should be able to considered the previous edit and then decide that I want to save my edit anyway. There's not much considering if you don't get a choice...